# Get specific Value from Json String Delphi XE8

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-xe8

I have this Json String in Delphi,

```json
{
  "bpd": {
    "euro": {
      "buying_rate": "48.50",
      "selling_rate": "52.70"
    },
    "dollar": {
      "buying_rate": "45.30",
      "selling_rate": "45.80"
    },
    "source": "https://www.popularenlinea.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Rates')/items"
  },
  "blh": {
    "euro": {
      "buying_rate": "48.50",
      "selling_rate": "52.00"
    },
    "dollar": {
      "buying_rate": "45.35",
      "selling_rate": "45.80"
    },
    "source": "http://www.blh.com.do/Inicio.aspx"
  }
}
```

I want extract the buying_rate and selling_rate for the dollar for the bank blh

i try this but i get AV

```
  var
  LJsonObj  : TJSONObject;
  LRows, LElements, LItem : TJSONValue;
begin
    LJsonObj    := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s),0) as TJSONObject;
  try
     LRows:=LJsonObj.Get(0).JsonValue;
     LElements:=TJSONObject(TJSONArray(LRows).Get(0)).Get(0).JsonValue;
     LItem :=TJSONObject(TJSONArray(LElements).Get(0)).Get(0).JsonValue;
     ShowMessage(TJSONObject(LItem).Get('buying_rate').JsonValue.Value);
  finally
     LJsonObj.Free;
  end;
```

Answer (score 14):

There are many errors in your code. The most significant is your repeated use of unchecked casts. When you write

```
TJSONArray(LRows)
```

you are telling the compiler that you know 100% for sure that `LRows` is descended from `TJSONArray`. Well, it isn't. Especially when you are dealing with external data you must not make such assumptions. You are then subject to the whims of the data that you receive. Use a checked cast instead

```
LRows as TJSONArray
```

Now, that's still wrong because `LRows` is not an array. In fact your JSON doesn't have any arrays at all. It just has objects. But when you use the checked cast the failure will be a meaningful error rather than an access violation.

This program reads the values you are looking for:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.JSON, System.IOUtils;

procedure Main;
var
  s: string;
  LJsonObj: TJSONObject;
  blh: TJSONObject;
  dollar: TJSONObject;
  rate: TJSONString;
begin
  s := TFile.ReadAllText('C:\desktop\json.txt');
  LJsonObj := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s), 0) as TJSONObject;
  try
    blh := LJsonObj.GetValue('blh') as TJSONObject;
    dollar := blh.GetValue('dollar') as TJSONObject;

    rate := dollar.GetValue('buying_rate') as TJSONString;
    Writeln(rate.Value);

    rate := dollar.GetValue('selling_rate') as TJSONString;
    Writeln(rate.Value);
  finally
    LJsonObj.Free;
  end;
end;

begin
  try
    Main;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

**Output**

```
45.35
45.80
```

I advise you to spend some time at the [JSON](http://www.json.org/) site to make sure that you have a very clear understanding of the terminology. You should have a clear understanding of what is meant by the terms object, array and value. At the moment I think that is lacking.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [jsonDoc](https://github.com/stijnsanders/jsonDoc) it would look something like this:

```
StrToFloat(JSON(JSON(JSON(TFile.ReadAllText('C:\desktop\json.txt'))['blh'])['dollar'])['buying_rate'])
```